# What is and how do you calculate the wind velocity design for wind turbines?

Tags: turbines, renewable-energy, wind-power

I am finding it difficult to get consensus on the definition of design wind speed for aeolic turbines.

I thought it was the velocity that corresponds to the maximum power output, but I have already heard that it could be the velocity that corresponds to lambda (tip speed ratio) equals 7.
What is this really about?

Comment: The velocity cubed...

Comment: You could start here: http://www.ewea.org/wind-energy-basics/faq/

Comment: In what context have you seen this phrase "design wind speed" used? I've seen **rated** wind speed, but not *design* wind speed.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of turbine dynamics, the pressure gradient is what determines mechanical motion. Creating a directional gradient for lateral motion perpendicular to pressure differential is what causes the turbine blades to move. Where the gradient is increased by larger surface area, wind velocity may be lower for action to appear.

Surprisingly, the biplane of Great War era was able to stay aloft at considerably lower speeds than single fixed wing craft. This principle applies to turbines would result in bi-bladed or even Tri-bladed turbines variable of motion at lower wind velocities with the risk that higher winds would possibly become deleterious to structural integrity of the blades.

Answer (score 0):

Wind speed is the speed of wind coming/hit the propeller surface perpendicularly, or inline to the turbine's axis for horizontal axis wind turbine (HAWT), or 90 degree perpendicular to axis of a vertical axis wind turbine (VAWT).

For HAWT (calculation for VAWT is quite different), the kinetic power of the wind is: half of the air density (rho) times cross-section (A) times power of 3 of wind-velocity (V^3). Or:

Kinetic power = 0.5*Rho*A*V^3.

Where:
A is 2*pi*r, with r is the blade's length.

So, kinetic power of wind is proportional to the air density (rho), affected significantly by the blades length, and affected very significant by the wind speed as it has power of 3 (multiplied three times).

What you are thinking about tip speed of the blade is another thing. It is related to the power efficiency of a propeller of an airplane or a fan. It will be related to reynold number, stall, laminar, etc. Mach 0.8 so far is claimed the most effective tips speed. Mean, if you have a big fan and the fan axis or shaft you connected to an engine to power it, if you force the fan speed more than mach 0.8 (0.8 of sound speed), you will lost much power (in horse power) without gaining more force generated by the fan (or propeller as commonly in airplane). So, the airplane speed or tip speed is maintained maximum mach 0.8, not more.

Clearly, the wind speed you are asking is the speed of the wind hitting or coming to the wind turbine blades, perpendicularly to the cross section, NOT the speed of the tip.